# JTable from resulset with mouseclicked function

Tags: javascript, java, jtable, tablemodel, defaulttablemodel

I have this Jtable from resultset, with mouseclicked function, which is actually working fine, when I clicked a row, it will provide me the correct row or record... but, the thing, is I have also a search function (using keyreleased), that will list all the search similar items... 
So, my concern, is when I have searched and my jtable was refreshed showing the searched items and when I clicked that row/record, it won't provide me the exact record... 
Would you know, what is the problem here?  or would you know, how to refresh my tablemodel?

Thank you so much!... really appreciate for any response...

Comment: Please, add your existing code and describe what you have tries.

Comment: Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(memberflSQL);

tblASMemberList.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

Comment: private void txtASMemberListSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                  
       model = (AbstractTableModel) tblASMemberList.getModel();
        String search = txtASMemberListSearch.getText().toUpperCase();
        TableRowSorter<AbstractTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        tblASMemberList.setRowSorter(tr);
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(search));
   }

Comment: private void tblASMemberListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             

        int index = tblASMemberList.getSelectedRow();
        model = (AbstractTableModel) tblASMemberList.getModel();

        String polno = model.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
        String lname = model.getValueAt(index, 1).toString();
        String fname = model.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();

 
        new MemberDtl().setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }

Comment: What happen is, when I search and clicked the row/record, it didn't provide me the correct row, i believe it is from the original table model... thank you so much for the response!

Comment: Put additional information on the post, not as comments. [mcve] would be best